# Adding Column for duplicates in PIG

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig, cloudera

I have some values like this,

```
tEn 1
teN 8
Ten 1
thrEE 2
tHRee 1
```

How do I add column 2 and generate this for all *case-insensitive* duplicates in column 1?

```
ten 10
three 3
```

I have tried using `GROUP`,

```
tmp = GROUP data BY (column1);
result = FOREACH tmp GENERATE
    group,
    SUM(data.column2) as count
```

But somehow it doesn't seem to give the right results. What do I do?

Comment: Try not to delete posts when some effort has been done to provide you an answer! I spent some minutes to get that `grep` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are case sensitive. You need to make them all lower case first so that they match up

```
lowerdata = FOREACH data GENERATE LOWER(column1), column2;
```

and then do what you were doing before.

```
tmp = GROUP lowerdata BY (column1);
result = FOREACH tmp GENERATE
    group,
    SUM(data.column2) as count
```